# Content security police on gh-page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, content-security-policy

I had no problems with web app when I hosted it locally. even now when i run `gh-pages -d build` (when i rename favicon.ico from create-react-app) it works for 3-5 minutes and after that when i visit [website](https://davitge.github.io/audio-ecommerce-website/) it shows `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://davitge.github.io/favicon.ico (“img-src”).`

index.html:

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

here you can see [source](https://github.com/DavitGe/audiophile-ecommerce-website)

Answer (score 1):

A content security policy is set somewhere (could be in code, webserver, load balancer, proxy, etc) that is restricting your loading of the image. Check response headers and meta tags for a policy. You will need to add whatever value %PUBLIC_URL% resolves to in the img-src directive. If img-src is not defined you could add it to default-src. If %PUBLIC_URL% is the host your are loading your page from you could use the value 'self' instead.